# Angular 2 agm library for google maps setting place by place id

Tags: angular, google-maps, typescript, angular2-google-maps

I am implementing in a page a google map where a place id is passed to me, I then need to obtain such place id and load the map with that marker. I was going through the documentation but its not clear on how i can target the map object from the `<agm-map>` tag so that i can set the place id. Here is part of the code:

```
  public latitude: number;
  public longitude: number;
  public zoom: number;
  public placeid: string;

  constructor(
    private mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader,
    private ngZone: NgZone
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
      //set google maps defaults
      this.zoom = 4;
      this.latitude = 39.8282;
      this.longitude = -98.5795;
      this.placeid = "ChIJMS2FahDQzRIRcJqX_aUZCAQ";

      //set current position
      this.setCurrentPosition();

      this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
            //How do i set the agm-map here to load the map with the placeid

      });
    }

    private setCurrentPosition() {
      if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
          this.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
          this.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
          this.zoom = 12;
        });
      }
    }
```

Then on the html file I have something like this:

```
<agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" [scrollwheel]="false" [zoom]="zoom">
      <agm-marker [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

I looked at the GOOGLE documentation and it looks like to set the place id you would need something like this

```
var request = {
  placeId: 'ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4'
};

service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.getDetails(request, callback);

function callback(place, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    createMarker(place);
  }
}
```

The problem i have is that i am not sure as to what to pass for `map` since i am using `<agm-map>`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `mapReady` output property of `agm-map`. Change your html to

```
<agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" [scrollwheel]="false" [zoom]="zoom" (mapReady)="mapReady($event)">
      <agm-marker [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

and define following functions in your component. This function will be called when your map is ready.

```
mapReady($event: any) { 
  // here $event will be of type google.maps.Map 
  // and you can put your logic here to get lat lng for marker. I have just put a sample code. You can refactor it the way you want.
  this.getLatLong('ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4', $event, null);
}

getLatLong(placeid: string, map: any, fn) {
    let placeService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    placeService.getDetails({
      placeId: placeid
      }, function (result, status) {
        console.log(result.geometry.location.lat());
        console.log(result.geometry.location.lng())
      });
  }
```

Change / refactor this sample code according to your need such that you are able set values to latitude and longitude parameters that you are passing to html.

```
<agm-marker [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude"></agm-marker>
```

Comment: Can u help me with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50998913/how-to-add-label-to-each-marker-angular-google-maps-angular-2

Comment: When I do this, I get "TypeError: google.maps.places is undefined". Everything else is working. I just can't get past the new google.maps.places line.

Comment: figured this out. you need to add libraries: ['places'] to the AgmCoreModule.forRoot entry in app.module.ts, and you need to add "types": ["googlemaps"] to "compilerOptions" in tsconfig.app.json