# How to add label to each marker angular google maps - Angular 2

Tags: angular, google-maps, label

I am using Angular 2 for my project . I would like to know how to add label to the marker using angular google maps. I am not getting a solution to add a label using Angular 2. 
Below is my html code . I am retrieving the places using ngFor . I need to tag the name object to the marker . Basically , when i hover on a marker , it should show that name

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <input placeholder="search for location" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" 
        spellcheck="off" type="text" class="form-control" #search [formControl]="searchControl">
      </div>
    <agm-map style="height: 600px" [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude">
        <agm-marker  *ngFor="let m of mapArrayList; let i = index" 
          [latitude]="m.latitude"
          [longitude]="m.longitude"
          label="m"
          (markerClick)="clickedMarker(m.id)"
         >

       </agm-marker>
    </agm-map>


mapArrayList:
0:
    address: XYZ
    name: ABC services Lts


ngOnInit() {
    this.latitude = 1.372611;
    this.longitude = 103.848076;
    this.mapArrayList = this.facilityListArray;
    console.log(this.mapArrayList);
     // set google maps defaults
     this.zoom = 40;

     // create search FormControl
     this.searchControl = new FormControl();

     // set current position
     this.setCurrentPosition();

     // load Places Autocomplete
    this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
      const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.searchElementRef.nativeElement, {
        componentRestrictions: {country: ['SG', 'IN']}
      });
      autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', () => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          // get the place result
          const place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();

          // verify result
          if (place.geometry === undefined || place.geometry === null) {
            window.alert('No details available for input: \'' + place.name + '\'');
            return;
          }

          // set latitude, longitude and zoom
          this.latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
          this.longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
          this.zoom = 100;
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can provide the label like this ...

```
<agm-map style="height: 600px" [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude">
        <agm-marker  *ngFor="let m of mapArrayList; let i = index" 
          [latitude]="m.latitude"
          [longitude]="m.longitude"
          [label]="m.label"
          (markerClick)="clickedMarker(m.id)"
         >

       </agm-marker>
    </agm-map>
```

Where variable `m.label` has a string value - usually a single uppercase character. (though you can use any string value)

In place of string value you can also use value of type `MarkerLabel` for providing more detailed info if you like that. Following is the structure of the MarkerLabel interface.

```
interface MarkerLabel {
  color: string;
  fontFamily: string;
  fontSize: string;
  fontWeight: string;
  text: string;
}
```

Comment: @Nancy - Does it help in resolving your problem?