# How to make a overlay for google maps refresh without refreshing everything else

Tags: html, angular, typescript, google-maps-api-3

Note this question is related to the one I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51104491/adding-night-overlay-to-google-maps-api)

In my html I am creating a overlay to a google map with

```
<agm-map ngDraggable [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" [zoom]="zoom" *ngIf="locations" (mapReady)="mapReady($event)" >
```

Where mapReady is defined as

```
  mapReady($event: any) { 
    console.log("about fire init");
    nite.init($event);
    setInterval(nite.refresh(),10000);
  }
```

Now the problem is that `nite.refresh()` is supposed to fire every 10 seconds but it only fires one time.  I'm not sure if this has something to do with my `ngOnInit()` which has a

```
timer(0, 10000).pipe(
      switchMap( _ => this.hawkerservice.fetchNews()
    )).pipe( map(...)).subscribe()
```

like function in it.  Could this be causing the problem?  The `nite.init(...)` is working fine i just need to be able to refresh the overlay without had refreshing the whole page which is what I am currently doing to get `nite` to refresh.  Any thoughts? sorry if english is not the best.

Comment: Just a quick note, when using `setInterval(nite.refresh(),10000);` you should be applying that to a component variable, and then using `ngOnDestroy() { ... }` to ensure it is removed when the component is destroyed.

Comment: Good point yes I need to do that thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered the answer which is I need to do

```
  mapReady($event: any) { 
    console.log("about fire init");
    nite.init($event);
    setInterval(function() { nite.refresh() }, 10000);
  }
```

In other words set Interval has to have a function() defined this way since nite is a js function not typescript.